# JQuery addClass not working on dynamically added item

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying the change the css class when i click on a dynamical added item. I do have the item in doStuffWithThisItem method, but it seems like the changes do not get save back into the dom tree.
But i can't get it to work. Can you spot what i am doing wrong?

```
        <style type="text/css">
        .selectedItem {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            function doStuffWithThisItem(item) {
                alert(item.id);
                jQuery(item.id).addClass('selectedItem');
            }

            function parseNodes(nodes, level) {

                var ol = document.createElement("ul");
                for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    ol.appendChild(parseChildNode(nodes[i], level));
                }

                return ol;
            }

            function parseChildNode(child, level) {

                var li = document.createElement('li');
                jQuery(li).html(child.title)
                    .attr("id", child.id)
                    .click(function () {

                        if (level == 1) {
                            doStuffWithThisItem(this);
                        }

                    });

                return li;
            }

            window.jsonData = [{
                    "title": "Item 1",
                    "id": "item1",
                    "description": "Item 1 description"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Item 2",
                    "id": "item2",
                    "description": "item 2 description"
                }];

            jQuery("#someDiv").html(parseNodes(jsonData, 1));
        });

    </script>


<div id="someDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change :

```
jQuery(item.id).addClass('selectedItem');
```

To:

```
jQuery("#"+item.id).addClass('selectedItem');
```

You have a mistake in the selector

Answer (score 1):

You already have the html element in your `doStuffWithThisItem` so you don't need to go get it with its `id`, which you weren't doing properly.

Try this:

```
function doStuffWithThisItem(item) {
     alert(item.id);
     jQuery(item).addClass('selectedItem');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with .on and .live handlers:

```
jQuery(li).html(child.title)
                .attr("id", child.id)
                .on('click',function () {

                    if (level == 1) {
                        doStuffWithThisItem(this);
                    }

                });
```

or

```
jQuery(li).html(child.title)
                .attr("id", child.id)
                .live('click',function () {

                    if (level == 1) {
                        doStuffWithThisItem(this);
                    }

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the item being added dynamically. I've run into that before myself, and had to use the `.on()` method to attach the events to the dynamically added item.

Also, I think your **selector** should just be the **item**, not the `item.id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(item.id).addClass('selectedItem');
```

Supposed to be

```
jQuery('#' + item.id).addClass('selectedItem'); //  OR   jQuery(item)
```

Missing the **# ID** selector..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yXq6Z/)**